# Flexslider and touch screen laptops, specifically Dell Inspiron

Tags: jquery, touch, flexslider

I am using Flexslider for a client site, and it works really well, except for maybe some new devices on the market. My client has a touch screen Dell Inspiron 15 laptop, so it has a track pad and it is touch enabled. She uses Firefox and has Windows 8.

She can't swipe the carousel with her laptop, but it works well on phones and tablets where the only means of interacting is through touch. I used to use Modernizr to detect touch, and I'd pass a boolean value to the Flexslider setup variable `touch`, but now I am letting FS do its own touch detection to see if that is better. Right now, its the same as Modernizr.

So, I am wondering if any is having similar issues, or have solved similar problems with the Flexslider library and multi-input devices. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying a few ideas outlined on this FS GH Issue: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/215

Comment: I have had the same problem. I add it as an issue here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/